# Template metaprogramming list

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to build a simple TList using template meta-programming and I have two questions for why it is not working. Here is the code:

```
struct TNull{};

template<typename T,typename U>
struct TList
{
    typedef T THead;
    typedef U TTail;

    THead head;
    TTail tail;
};

template<typename T>
void Foo(TList<T,TNull> &list)
{
    std::cout<<list.head<<"  ";
}

template<typename T,typename U>
void Foo(TList<T,U> &list)
{
    std::cout<<list.head<<" ";
    //Foo<int,TNull>(list.tail);  // COMM_1
    Foo<decltype(list.tail.head),decltype(list.tail.tail)>(list.tail); //COMM_2
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    TList<int,TList<int,TNull>> list;
    Foo(list);
    return 0;
}
```

First, I would like to know how to write the **COMM_2** line so the template will expand until it reaches the TNull then it stops. I tried different methods and none of it works

The second question is if I write the expansion by myself (like in **COMM_1**) I expect the compiler to pick the first Foo overload but it doesn't, it gives me an error. Why is this behavior? I was expecting the compiler to pick the best match for a specific set of arguments.

I am testing this feature using Visual c++ 2010, which has no support for *variadic template arguments*, and this is for a project at my workplace so switching compilers is not an option for me.

Comment: If you provide a default argument for the second template parameter of `TList`, you wouldn't need to manually insert a `TNull`. E.g. `template<typename T, typename U = TNull> struct TList; TList<int,TList<int>> my_list;`

Comment: Nice addition ! Thank you for your post !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `Foo(list.tail)`. The compiler will determine the function to call and deduce the template parameters based on the types of the function arguments. This code works in gcc under `-std=c++98`, and prints "1 2 \n".

```
#include <iostream>

struct TNull{};

template<typename T,typename U>
struct TList {
    typedef T THead;
    typedef U TTail;

    THead head;
    TTail tail;
};

template<typename T>
void Foo(TList<T,TNull> &list)
{
    std::cout << list.head << "  ";
}

template<typename T,typename U>
void Foo(TList<T,U> &list)
{
    std::cout << list.head << " ";
    Foo(list.tail);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    TList<int,TList<int,TNull> > list;
    list.head = 1;
    list.tail.head = 2;
    Foo(list);
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this will not work with empty lists. For that, you should write your `Foo` functions so that the base case is a `TNull`, as opposed to a `TList` with a `TNull` tail.